# list the filenames without showing the parent path

Tags: java

I am listing all the files names in a given directory( recursively). That includes showing the file names in sub-directories also.

```
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
    // Recursively search for all the resource files.
    Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(file, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
    for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        File fileIter = (File) iterator.next();
        System.out.println("File = " + fileIter.getPath());

    }
```

Where File is the parent directory ("C:\Users\sd\Desktop\sdsd)
Now the code above works file and list me all the files in the that directory and sub directory, like

> C:\Users\sd\Desktop\sdsd\TagCategory\healthoutcomes_queries\Neurological.txt

but I want to show only (the path inside of the parent path)

> TagCategory\healthoutcomes_queries\Neurological.txt

How can I do that.

Comment: Is there any reason why you chose to use raw (non-generic) classes? I mean it's 2017, not 2001.

Comment: I didnt mean to keep them non-generic. I just copied the paste in hurry. I have fixed it in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Path.relativize()`

> Constructs a relative path between this path and a given path.
>
> Relativization is the inverse of resolution. This method attempts to
>   construct a relative path that when resolved against this path, yields
>   a path that locates the same file as the given path. For example, on
>   UNIX, if this path is "/a/b" and the given path is "/a/b/c/d" then the
>   resulting relative path would be "c/d".

So you just need to create a relative path from the parent path by invoking `parentPath.relativize(filePath)` and do it for each file :

```
Path parentPath = Paths.get(FILE_PATH);

for (Iterator<File> iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){     
    Path filePath = iterator.next().toPath();
    Path relativePath = parentPath.relativize(filePath);
    System.out.println("File = " + relativePath );  
}
```

Note that you should use a generic collection to avoid casts : `Collection<File>`, and the modern idiom for looping through iterators using the "enhanced for loop" is cleaner to read:

```
for (File file : files) {     
    System.out.println("File = " +
         parentPath.relativize(file.toPath()));  
}
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than using `substring()`

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using `Paths.get(file.toURI())` instead of `file.toPath()`?

Comment: Can't resist: `files.stream().map( f -> f.toPath()).map(parentPath::relativeize).forEach(f -> System.out.println("File = " + f));`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException No good reason. Probably a bad habit to invoke `toURI()`. Thanks for the feedback.I edited. It is cleaner like that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add substring:

```
fileIter.getPath().substring(file.length())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring command to get that value as per the below..

If that parent directory is going to remain the same length then it would simply be

```
fileIter.getPath().substring(25);
```

This will get all of the characters after the 25th character in the string, if you wanted to omit the .txt for example you can specify where the substring will end, the below takes three off the total length.

```
fileIter.getPath().substring(25, fileIter.getPath().length() - 3);
```

For more details on the substring method see https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-substring-method-example/

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of complicating your code by using old third-party libraries? Just use plain Java: it does exactly the same thing as your multi-line method:

```
Path root = Paths.get(FILE_PATH);
Files.walk(root).forEach(path -> System.out.println("File = " + root.relativize(path)));
```